# Prove that a full binary tree has $\frac{N+1}{2}$ leaves

Tags: induction, trees

$N$ is the total number of nodes. It is to prove that the number of leaves equals $\frac{N+1}{2}$

I guess this can be proven by induction. The smallest full binary tree is $N=1$ with $\frac{1+1}{2} = 1$ leave. I further guess that the induction hypothesis must deal with the fact that the formula above is valid for subtrees. Obviously the number of nodes of a full binary tree must be odd. But I think this is statement you can't take for true without proof.

Induction hypothesis:

$$L(k)=\frac{k+1}{2}$$ where $k<N$ and $k=2i+1$ with $i\in\mathbb{N_0}$

Induction step:

$$L(i) = \frac{2i+1+1}{2}=\frac{2i+2}{2}=i+1$$
$$L(i+1) = L(i) + 1$$
$$L(i+1) = i + 1+1=i+2=\frac{k-1}{2}+2=\frac{k+3}{2}$$

But that doesn't make sense. I am happy about any hint.

Edit:
Solution:

$$N_d=1+\sum_{i=2}^{d}(2r_{i-1})$$
$$N_{d+1}=1+\sum_{i=2}^{d}(2r_{i-1})+2r_d$$
$$L_{d+1}=L_d+r_d$$
$$L_{d+1}=\frac{N_d+1}{2}+r_d=\frac{1+\sum_{i=2}^{d}(2r_{i-1})+1}{2}+r_d=\frac{1+\sum_{i=2}^{d}(2r_{i-1})+1+2r_d}{2}=\frac{N_{d+1}+1}{2}$$

Comment: Try induction after the depth of the tree instead of $N$

Comment: The questions linked are assuming a perfect tree with all leaves on the same level. But I am looking for a proof for only a full binary tree. This is different from a perfect one because not all leaves are on the same laevel. So the approach using the depth doesn't work out well in my opinion.

Comment: I have used the proof for perfect binary trees and appended an argument for full binary trees in my answer below. I think the proof should be complete and I hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This answer is a solution for full binary trees**

Use induction by the number of nodes $N$. For $N=1$ it's clear, so assume that all full binary trees with $n\leq N$ nodes have $L_n = \frac{n+1}{2}$ leaves (induction hypothesis). Let's take an arbitrary full tree with $N+1$ nodes. As $N\geq 1$ we will have at least $2$ leaves. Choose one pair of leaves of the same depth with the same parent and remove them.

We get a new tree with $n=N-1< N$ nodes which is still full (because every node has either two children or none and this condition is not disregarded), so we can use our induction hypothesis, which tells us that this smaller tree has $L_{N-1} = \frac{N-1+1}{2}$ leaves. However, the original tree has exactly one leaf more than the smaller tree (the $2$ children are replaced by $1$ parent), so we have a total of

$$
L_{N+1} = L_{N-1} + 1 = \frac{N}{2} + 1 = \frac{N+2}{2} = \frac{(N+1)+1}{2}
$$
leaves, which finishes the induction proof.

Comment: What exactly is $N_0$? It is a binary tree with an even number of nodes not constituting a full binary tree. So $N$ should be smaller than $N_0$. I understand the concept but I am not sure if that is formaly correct.

Comment: $N_0$ is the number I'm using induction over. As I need a strong induction hypothesis (not only for the $N$ before, but for ALL $N\leq N_0$), I introduced this $N_0$. I can rewrite this using $N$ as well so that you don't get confused. Is this clearer now? I don't see why it shouldn't be formally incorrect

Comment: I don't see where you need "even number of nodes"? That is nowhere mentioned or used in the proof

Comment: The reason why I am confused is having a full binary tree with N nodes and removing one node ($N-1$) would not fulfill the properties of a full binary tree anymore.

Comment: That's why I remove two nodes (two leaves with highest depth) from a tree with $N+1$ nodes

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is a solution for complete and perfect binary trees**

You shouldn't do induction by $N$, but induction by the depth of the tree $d$.

The induction start is the same for $N=d=1$. Let's look at the induction step $d\to d+1$: We will not only show the number of leaves by induction but also the number of nodes $N_d$ by induction:

Take a perfect binary tree $B_{d+1}$ of depth $d+1$ with $B_d$ as part of this tree (just the last layer is missing). We know that each leaf of $B_d$ (the tree with depth $d$) transforms into two leaves in the next layer $d+1$. By induction hypothesis $B_d$ has $L_d=\frac{N_d+1}{2}$ leaves and $N_d=2^{d}-1$ nodes (we show this number using induction as well). Now we add $2$ nodes for each leaf and each leaf turns into two leaves. That means that the new number of nodes is

$$
N_{d+1} = N_d + 2L_d =2^d-1 + 2\cdot \frac{N_d+1}{2} =2^d-1+(2^d-1+1) = 2\cdot 2^d-1 = 2^{d+1}-1
$$

and the number of leaves is
$$
L_{d+1} = 2L_d =\frac{N_d+1}{2} \cdot 2 = \frac{2^d-1+1}{2}\cdot 2 = \frac{2^{d+1}}{2} = \frac{2^{d+1}-1+1}{2} = \frac{N_{d+1}+1}{2}
$$

This finishes the proof.

Edit: You can generalize above result for complete binary trees as well:

In general you have not $N_d=2^d-1$ nodes, but $N_d=2^{d-1}-1+2k$ nodes with $1 \leq k\leq 2^{d-1}$ (in the last layer some pairs of two nodes are added, but at least one pair of nodes is added). As above denote with $B_{d+1}$ the full binary tree of depth $d+1$ (with only $2k$ nodes of depth $d+1$) and with $B_d$ the perfect binary tree that comes from $B_{d+1}$ after removing all nodes of depth $d+1$. We then have the formula ($.^p$ denotes the values for the perfect binary tree):
$$N_{d+1} = N_d^p + 2r$$ for $r$ the number of pairs of children ($N_d^p$ from the perfect binary tree) and
$$L_{d+1} = L_d^p + r.$$ The $+r$ is derived as follows: $r$ leaves of $B_d$ get two children. That means that we get an additional of $r$ leaves and not an additional of $L_d^p$ leaves as for perfect binary trees.

Using the formulas for perfect binary trees shown in the previous induction yields:

$$N_{d+1} = 2^d-1+2r$$
$$L_{d+1} = \frac{N_d^p+1}{2}+r = \frac{(2^d-1)+1+2r}{2} = \frac{(2^d-1+2r)+1}{2} = \frac{N_{d+1}+1}{2}$$

Thus the formula is correct for full binary trees as well.

Comment: That's only true if it is a perfect binary tree, correct? Otherwise $N_{d+1}=N_{d}+2L_{d}$ wouldn't be valid. But I am looking for a proof for full binary trees.

Comment: Ah okay, I though that full means perfect, but it seems that is not the case. You can generalize the above proof to general full binary trees as well. I will add that argument

Comment: Thanks for the effort, really. But I think, this proof is only valid for complete binary trees. For a full one $r$ must be $r_{d}$ for a specific level. So $N_{d} = 1+\sum_{i=2}^d 2r_{i-1}$ and $N_{d+1} = N_{d} + 2r_{d}=1+\sum_{i=2}^d 2r_{i-1} + 2r_{d}$. $L_{d+1}=L_{d}+r_{d}$ remains. If you put all together like you did it comes to the same result. Are my thoughts correct?

Comment: Damn, you are correct. My mother language is german, that's why I change up the different tree-definitions, sorry for that. For full trees indeed using depth does not help

Comment: I added a new answer for full trees which really should be correct now :D

Answer (score 0):

HINT: There is exactly 1 vertex of degree 2, the remaining $N-1$ vertices each have either degree 3 or 1. There must be $N-1$ edges total, so letting $A$ be the number of leaves i.e.,equivalently, $A$ is the number of degree-1 vertices, the Handshaking Lemma gives the following equation:

$$2+A+3(N-A-1) = 2N-2.$$

[The sums of the degrees of $T$ must add up to twice the number of edges in $T$.] This implies $A$ must be indeed $\frac{N+1}{2}$. [Notice we don't even need that $T$ is complete, only that every nonleaf vertex save for exactly one nonleaf vertex, has degree 3. This is a property a complete binary tree satisfies, but there are many other binary trees on $N$ vertices that are not complete and still satisfy this as well.]

Comment: How can a vertex be of degree 3? That would mean a vertex has 3 subtrees which isn't possible in a binary tree. Am I wrong?

Comment: A vertex $v$ has a parent, and then 2 children, so degree 1+2=3.